# Issue accessing a Realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a very simple web page that I am trying to set using firebase; but for some reason it is not working.

Here is the index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.14.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.14.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.14.4/firebase-database.js"></script>
    ......
    <style media="screen">
    ......
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is a firebase test page.

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

    <script>
      // App's Firebase configuration
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "A.......A",
        authDomain: "myapp-6638jj.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://myapp-6638jj.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "myapp-6638jj",
        storageBucket: "myapp-6638jj.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "3.....6",
        appId: "1:....:web:.....",
        measurementId: "G-73RX..XES"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase.analytics();
    </script>

    <script>
      var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('MyList');
      dbRef.set({"field1": "XX-UUU","field2": "yy-EEE"});
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Beside, for testing purposes I have set up the DB access rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

After loading the page I expect to see some data written to the Realtime database, but it is totally empty.

In the Web Console I get this error message:

```
ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
```

For those who would be tempted to say:
This error already has an answer I want to point out that the error message is not:

```
ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined
```

which indeed has an answer but doesn't solve my problem.

Before making this post I have of course tried out a few variations of the code above but none worked.

Can somebody see (or guess) what I am doing wrong for this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following script after the body tag:

```
  <body>
    This is a firebase test page.
  <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->
 <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

    <script>
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-the-cdn

Comment: You mean the problem is the position of the line containing "firebase-app.js" ? I will move it and see.

Comment: I have already fail 2 trials. Where exactly am supposed to put this line?

Comment: just copy it as it is

Comment: "Add the following script after the body tag" means the beginning to me. And "the bottom of the HTML" means the end. So I am not quite sure what it finally means.

Comment: I mean add the script after u open the body tag, as in the answer `<body>`//scripts</body>`

Comment: Well, I still get the message "ReferenceError: firebase is not defined".

Comment: Even after moving the lines after <body>.

Answer (score 1):

if you get a firebase undefined error, you may have misspelled the scripts. I suggest you check the scripts. it may work if the scripts are between body tags and the defer property is not defined.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script> // ıts must be first
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Comment: As you can see in the post, there is no misspelling.

Comment: have you tried removing the `<defer>` feature ? with the defer feature, the code will run after the page has finished loading completely. you now right  ?

Comment: You are right, removing the "defer" makes a difference.